# Evaluating a limit in the complex plane.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How should I approach evaluating the following limit?

$$\lim_{z\to\infty} \frac{e^{iz}}{z}$$

I've tried using power series, euler's formula... yet to no avail.

Comment: In the complex plane, we say that $f(z)$ has a $z \rightarrow \infty$ limit if $f(1/w)$ has a $w \rightarrow 0$ limit. Try that.

Comment: In that case, I'd end up with $$\lim_{t\to0} te^{i\frac{1}{t}}=0*\infty$$ which does not seem very useful.

Comment: And what is the Laurent expansion about $t = 0$ for that? Is there a singularity? A pole? Removable? Essential?

Comment: We actually haven't gotten that far in my complex class.

Comment: Okay, well, even without that machinery, I can tell you that you should try to show the limit does not exist. Show that two different sequences of points whose limit is $0$ leads to different sequential limits.

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong I'm not sure I understand your approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z\to\infty$ along the real line we have $|e^{iz}|=1$ and $1/|z|\to 0$ so the limit along the real line is $0$.

If $z=-iy$ for $y$ positive real, its absolute value is $e^y/y$ which, as $y\to+\infty$, will become arbitrarily large.

The limit therefore does not exist since the expression tends to different values according to the line along which $z\to\infty$.